# Read Float from MySQL into dictionary with Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to read values from my MySQL db and store them in a dict in Python using mysql connector. 
My db has 3 columns (`MDK, JT, tp`) and looks like this:

```
`1   1  1.9
 1   2  1.77
 1   3  2.5
 2   1  1.9
 2   2  1.77
 2   3  2.5 `
```

So far i tried:

```js
import mysql
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(....)

mycursor = conn.cursor(dictionary = True)

query = ("SELECT * FROM 'test'")

mycursor.execute(query)

tp = {}

for row in mycursor:
  tp[row["MDK"], row["JT"]] = float(row["tp"])
  
mycursor.close()
```

The values that are saved in the dict at the moment are:

```
`tp[1,1] = 1
 tp[1,2] = 1
 tp[1,3] = 2
 tp[2,1] = 1
 tp[2,2] = 1
 tp[2,3] = 2`
```

As you can see, only the integers are saved, but I need floats. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Insert to output of `describe table test`

Comment: what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: execute `describe table test` and put output here

Comment: I declared the variables as Decimal in MySQL, that leads python to accept the right value. Unfortunately I cant explain why it doesnt work if I declare them as Float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared the variables as Decimal in MySQL, that leads python to accept the right value. Unfortunately I cant explain why it doesnt work if I declare them as Float

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly because of how you are outputting the values of `tp`. Are you sure you are not using `%d` to display float values?

In other words, try running 
`print(["tp[%d,%d]=%4.2f\n"%(i, j, tp[i,j]) for i in range(1, 3) for j in range(1, 4)])`
Note the `%4.2f`, this is used to display floats

Comment: No, I dont think so because the calculations I do later and which are based on these dictionaries also only take the integer value and hence, are not accurate